# Spanish word list for statistical analysis

Tags: recursos, lingüística

I need a Spanish word list, as simple as that.
The more complete it is, the better, it should contain as many words as to be a statistically relevant sample.
It can be in any format, xml, excel, txt, etc...

Example:
`a
al
ala
alambre
...`
(Doesn't need to be in any specific order)

Then I can import it into a database and make some statistical analysis about letter and syllable frequency and in what combinations do they appear, where in the word, etc.

---

Necesito una lista de palabras del español. Cuanto más completa, mejor.
Debería contener una cantidad de palabras como para tener una muestra estadísticamente relevante.
Puede estar en cualquier formato, xml, excel, txt, etc...

Ejemplo:
`a
al
ala
alambre
...`
(No tiene que estar en ningún orden específico)

La necesito para importarla en una base de datos y luego poder hacer análisis estadísticos sobre la frecuencia de letras y sílabas, y la incidencia de sus combinaciones, en qué parte de la palabra aparecen, etc.

Comment: Hey, sorry the question got closed. It is off topic because it isn't asking a particular question about spanish, this could be exchanged with french or german with no difference. If you change the question for a more exact answer I'll be happy to reopen it. Thanks! :)

Comment: ¿Te serviría una lista de palabras conjugadas para Scrabble? Tengo una, sólo incluye palabras de 2 a 13 letras, y no incluye las tildes.

Comment: @Joze: Oh sorry, so should I post this exact same question in linguistics?

Comment: I'm sure this question would be closed on linguistics, as well. I'd suggest searching for spell check dictionaries in your target language(s). aspell/ispell come with some that are freely available. Google is your friend.

Comment: Actually we've answered similar questions on linguistics.SE before. Tag it with [`resources`](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) and [`corpora`](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corpora). But do try and tell us how hard you looked so far and what you need it for, especially if [`computational linguistics`](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-linguistics) is involved.

Comment: Thanks @hippietrail. I think I did tell what I need it for: "Then I can import it into a database and make some statistical analysis about letter and syllable frequency and in what combinations do they appear, where in the word, etc"
How hard I looked? very hard, that's why I resorted here. 
Making a question here seems harder than explaining why you're entering the USA from Mexico with a bag of cocaine under your clothes.

Comment: Sorry @Petruza I don't mean to pick on you, I'm just trying to help you find a way to ask a question on one of the SE sites that will have the best chance of getting a good answer. Some of the language sites believe their site should only be about speaking, writing, and comprehending the language and nothing else related to the language. And of course Stack Exchange has its own rules they want their beta sites to follow before they will allow them to graduate to full sites. These things make it hard for some people to find the right site and way to ask their question and that's unfortunate. ):

Comment: This question has been re-asked on linguistics. I'd like to cross reference the two by linking: **[Searching for a Spanish word list for statistical analysis](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2081/searching-for-a-spanish-word-list-for-statistical-analysis)**

Comment: For future reference: I came upon this post (and the partner post on linguistics) while searching for a good Spanish word list on the web. I want you to know that you did a disservice to more than one person and I invite other people to also indicate if they searched in vain for a good answer here. (And you can look up that I have been very active at german.SE, so you don't need to tell me that this is due to Stackexchange that you chose not to answer this question and/or make a page of ressources.)

Comment: @Phira sorry, but this question is *clearly* off-topic.  If requests for resources are on-topic on German.SE that's their business, but they aren't on this one.  As hippietrail noted, such requests *are* on-topic on Linguistics.SE, but they do require showing some effort of having looked and been unsuccessful.  No doubt on Mathematics.SE (which I see you're active in), a question like "show me how to solve [equation] because I can't. [end of question]" would be closed, unless it showed an attempt or had a specific issue in attempting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't you make use of the words that come in Spanish dictionaries for Firefox, for example? I have 2 Spanish dictionaries installed (Argentina, Spain) and they have 72886 and 54875 words respectively. You can easily import them into a database table. They are plain text files separated by EOL.

I [just read](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#q=how%20many%20words%20are%20there%20in%20the%20spanish%20language&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=6mdaT4DvDefV0QH3h9HlDA&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d54c0545889e0871&biw=1280&bih=939&ix=sea&ion=1) that the Spanish language has about 100K words; therefore, the 73K words in the Argentinian dictionary for Firefox should be a good start for your analysis.

Comment: Gracias! no entiendo por qué me cerraron la pregunta, si esto no tiene que ver con el lenguaje y su uso, no entiendo.